# Ole db Query error missing operator

Tags: mysql, ms-access

i'm currently making a guide tool. i connected to my accdb file and all works fine.

Now i want wo select the Name of Monster who drops item XY.

the monster has 19 drop fields , namen from a_item_0 to a_item_19.

my query is:

```
string query = "SELECT a_name FROM waffen WHERE a_item_0= " 
  + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_1= '" + textBox21.Text 
  + "' OR a_item_2= '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_3 = '" 
  + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_4= '" + textBox21.Text 
  + "' OR a_item_5= '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_6= '" 
  + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_7 = '" 
  + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_8 = '" + textBox21.Text 
  + "' OR a_item_9 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_10 = '" 
  + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_11 = '" + textBox21.Text 
  + "' OR a_item_12 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_13 = '" 
  + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_14 = '" + textBox21.Text 
  + "' OR a_item_15 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_16 = '" 
  + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_17 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_18 = '" 
  + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_19 = '" + textBox21.Text + ";";
```

Maybe someone sees the error i look for more than 2 hours now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've missed the first and last string delimiters

```
string query = "SELECT a_name FROM waffen WHERE a_item_0= '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_1= '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_2= '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_3 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_4= '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_5= '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_6= '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_7 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_8 = '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_9 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_10 = '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_11 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_12 = '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_13 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_14 = '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_15 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_16 = '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_17 = '" + textBox21.Text + "' OR a_item_18 = '" + textBox21.Text 
    + "' OR a_item_19 = '" + textBox21.Text + "';";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be missing the very first singe-quote in your query string.

WHERE a_item_0= '" + textBox21.Text + "'